# Spring Boot project in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse-oxygen

I am creating a Spring Boot Application in eclipse oxygen.I have followed the following steps:

**File->New->Spring Boot->Spring Starter Project**

When the wizard opens up I am getting the following error::

**SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

[image]

I am connected to Internet and also able to connect to Eclipse Market Place

***Can anyone figure out the issue??***

Comment: I always go to the website, do some clicking, then I download the archive, unpack and import. Always works!

Comment: which archive you are referring to?as far as I know spring boot plugin is installed by default with oxygen version of eclipse

Comment: You can simply click Generate project and download the archive.

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered the exactly same issue earlier.  To make it work, changed Network Connections mode to Manual. Follow this path.

> Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections Change mode to Manual

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Eclipse anymore ... But, which Java version are you using ?
This error, not especially linked to Eclipse, appears when JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) is not present. Did you try to install it ?

- Download [JCE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)
- Copy `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` to `$JAVAHOME/jre/lib/security`.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8.0_151.